# Two type errors attempting to patch complex recursive type signature. Help understand and fix?

Tags: typescript

I'd like to use a pipe and compose library built around an impressive recursive type signature. While it worked in TS 3.4, it doesn't work in 4.4.  I've been trying to update it and submit a patch, though my typescript skills are insufficient to understand the cause of the type misalignment (ts:2322) error that i'm getting.

There appear to be two TS errors that prevent the code from working in 4.4.  Can you help me understand the cause of those errors, and what solutions for them would preserve the pipe's existing 3.4 behavior?  (for reference, "pipe" is equivalent to lodash and fp-ts "flow" functions)

[playground](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-pipe-and-compose?file=index.ts) To modify the code.  It is a concatenation of the original [types file](https://github.com/babakness/pipe-and-compose-types/blob/master/index.ts) and [code file](https://github.com/babakness/pipe-and-compose/blob/master/src/index.ts) without modifying the content.  Plus a [blog post](https://dev.to/hemaka/introducing-the-recursive-pipe-and-compose-types-3g9o) walking through the concepts.

Relevant code sections below:

```
type ExtractFunctionArguments < Fn > = Fn extends  ( ...args: infer P ) => any  ? P : never

type ExtractFunctionReturnValue<Fn> = Fn extends  ( ...args: any[] ) => infer P  ? P : never

type BooleanSwitch<Test, T = true, F = false> = Test extends true ? T : F

type AnyFunction = ( ...args: any[] ) => any

export type AnyFunction1 = ( a: any ) => any

// This is used as an arbitrary literal that should not match anything else.
type Arbitrary = 'It is now 1554792354 seconds since since Jan 01, 1970'

// An type to test if a type is `any` within a specific context
type IsAny<O, T = true, F = false> = Arbitrary extends O
  ? any extends O
    ? T
    : F
  : F

/* first error is here on 'next' self-reference */  
export type Pipe<Fns extends any[], IsPipe = true, PreviousFunction = void, InitalParams extends any[] = any[], ReturnType = any> = {
  'next': ( ( ..._: Fns ) => any ) extends ( ( _: infer First, ..._1: infer Next ) => any )
    ? PreviousFunction extends void
        ? Pipe<Next, IsPipe, First, ExtractFunctionArguments<First>, ExtractFunctionReturnValue<First> >
        : ReturnType extends ExtractFunctionArguments<First>[0]
          ? Pipe<Next, IsPipe, First, InitalParams, ExtractFunctionReturnValue<First> >
          : IsAny<ReturnType> extends true
            ? Pipe<Next, IsPipe, First, InitalParams, ExtractFunctionReturnValue<First> >
            : {
              ERROR: ['Return type ', ReturnType , 'does comply with the input of', ExtractFunctionArguments<First>[0]],
              POSITION: ['Position of problem for input arguments is at', Fns['length'], 'from the', BooleanSwitch<IsPipe, 'end', 'beginning'> , 'and the output of function to the ', BooleanSwitch<IsPipe, 'left', 'right'>],
            }
    : never
  'done': ( ...args: InitalParams ) => ReturnType,
}[
  Fns extends []
    ? 'done'
    : 'next'
]

export type PipeFn = <Fns extends [AnyFunction, ...AnyFunction1[]]>(
  ...fns: Fns & Pipe<Fns> extends AnyFunction ? Fns : never
) => Pipe<Fns>;

/* second error is here: the implementation doesn't match the PipeFn signature */  
export const pipe: PipeFn =
  (entry: AnyFunction, ...funcs: AnyFunction1[]) =>
  (...arg: unknown[]) =>
    funcs.reduce((acc, item) => item.call(item, acc), entry(...arg));
```

Comment: If I look at [the original code](https://tsplay.dev/Wzo3kw) in TS4.4 I'm not seeing errors; are you saying that you started modifying things and then saw errors [as a result of your modifications](https://tsplay.dev/mx5AxW)?  I mean, that's a daunting amount of code to wade through, and it's not clear to me where your modifications are or why you're making them (saying things "don't work" isn't quite enough for me to figure out).  I don't know if you'll get people willing to spend the time and effort sifting through this; could you work on producing a [mre] of code with the same issue?

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I copied/pasted the code directly from the types and code repos into the sandbox link (one file each, concatenated into a single file in the sandbox).  No changes to either.  The errors show up in the sandbox just as they did locally.  While I included everything for context and to avoid making changes, the relevant parts are almost entirely contained in the snippet above.  I'll include the utility things like AnyFunction now.

Comment: https://catchts.com/FP-style#compose